# Is it possible to analyze data only from main folder without subfolders in Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

I want to exclude a subfolder when analyzing data of a website. In that case, a blog with different purposes from the main website.

Moving the blog in a subdomain would be the best solution, but I can't do it.

I wish to check the homepage and the rest of the website indipendently from the blog. So:

1. www.example.com, without /blog/
2. www.example.com/blog

If I add the subfolder as a new site in Search Console, the tool would also show me data from /blog subfolder.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

As said here by Sezhers
[How to see the searched terms that refer to my homepage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81876/how-to-see-the-searched-terms-that-refer-to-my-homepage#answer-81895)
in Google Search Console you can filter in or out pages and folders of your website.

In my case, I use the filter "URL is" as in below screenshots.

[image: 1st passage for filtering pages in Google Search Console]

[image: 2nd passage for filtering pages in Google Search Console]

Answer (score 2):

No Google Webmaster Tools isn't setup that way. If you need that much granularity into your site, GWT isn't the right tool anyways. I don't think it even has an active product manager right now.