# How to see the searched terms that refer to my homepage

Tags: seo, google-analytics, search-engines

I have put the google analytics script in my page, but I need to know the search terms that users use in order to refer to my page. How can I use google analytics to find such terms? (For example somebody searches my name in google and it directs him to my homepage).

Comment: did you try to search on google like `site:www.yoursite.com`

Comment: @HelpingHands yes but it doesn't even show my page

Comment: then you should check for your robot.txt first , is that file correct?

Comment: Give us the link of your website. About your question: are you asking how people link to your site with links <a href="">text</a>? Or what people use as a search query on google or bing to find your site?

Comment: @lucgenti I just modified the question to include the page. I am looking for search queries.

Comment: @HelpingHands It doesn't have any robot.txt because it is a one-page homepage.

Comment: @emab you need google webmaster tools for better reports, because GA doesn't report all your keywords for privacy reasons. Anyway, you can look at them under acquisition -> campaign -> organic keywords

Answer (score 2):

You should actually use Google Webmaster Tools for this kind of information. You can connect your website with GWT using your Google Analytics account and then just wait for a couple of days until the search queries will be shown in Search Traffic -> Search Analytics

You can put in a filter for just the home page while still showing queries:

[image]

Comment: I can't find a way to get a list of search queries for a specific page out of GWT.    They have a new interface that to the "Search Analytics" that lets you filter by page, but then it only shows a list of pages, not a list of search terms.

Comment: Are you sure you are using it right? When I enter a specific page into the filter it shows a list of keywords this page is being shown for in search results. 
And if "Search Analytics" doesn't work for you, try to change back to "Search Queries".

Comment: You are correct, it is possible.   I edited a screen shot into your answer and reversed my vote from a down vote to an up vote.

Comment: That would be also an answer to this question I did in past http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75870/is-it-possible-to-separate-main-folder-from-subfolder-in-webmaster-tools

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Google Analytics account and do the following:

1) Acquisition - All Traffic -  Channels

2) Select Organic Search

3) Add a Secondary Dimension - Landing Page

3) Use the Advanced Filter and set it to Include - Landing Page - Exactly Matching - / or in your case /~u5410055/

[image]

You should now see all of your keywords for the home page.

Keep in mind that any searches that are done by users logged into their G account will not show up and will be labeled (not provided). There is a work around for that so that you can at least see the pages those unknown keywords lead to. You will have to setup a filter for your view. Got to Admin - > Select the view you want this to apply to - Filter - New Filter. Below is a screen shot of settings:

[image]

Comment: It is actually "Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Channels".   For my site this yields "(not provided) 86.92%" which is hardly useful.   I do get a list of keywords below that, but the stats are not likely to be accurate because of the high number of not provided. Is there a way to get the same report from Search Engine Optimization data that is pulled from Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: In the case of the specific poster, his landing page for his home page would need to match `/~u5410055/` because his home page is not at the root level.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the notes. I updated my answer with both. My not provided is around 33%. For the rest I have it set to at leas tell me which page is getting picked up using a filter. There is no way to pull it from SEO report data in GA because your second dimension options are limited to 'country' and 'google property'. Plus, the data you get is only data from the past 90 days or so.

Comment: Correction. 33% is the number for keywords that are "provided".

Comment: Not provided is annoying, but I think this is the best answer possible if there is no way to get it out of webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get a good answer without google analytics.

If you scan your site through a keyword density analyzer, you'll find out important sets of keywords you can use in google search to find your site.

I use textalyser.net to check my keyword density. Another beauty is that it has a prominence measurement that shows how important groups of words are in your page.

Also, you may use google webmaster tools search analytics section to see what people are searching for in order for your site to appear in their search results pages. Also, you'll see the search engine position (rank) of your site based on the keywords.

I'm sure if you play with google (and other) tools long enough, you'll get a better idea which of your pages pop up depending on search terms.